# Drawing a WPF complex path with different stroke colours

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas, bezier

I am binding an `ItemsControl` in my View to a `List<BezierSeg>` where

```
class BezierSeg
{
    public Point ControlPoint1 { get; set; }
    public Point ControlPoint2 { get; set; }
    public Point EndPoint { get; set; }
    public Point StartPoint { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public SolidColorBrush Brush
    {
        get
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Color);
        }
    }
}
```

...and using a converter to create a `PathFigure` per BezierArc.

Unsurprisingly, this is not very performant compared to a single `PathGeometry` containing all the points necessary to draw the complex path.

But if I use the latter approach, I lose the capability of giving a different colour for each `BezierSeg`.

Is there a way I can describe a `PathGeometry` and still give different colours for different segments of this geometry? If not, how would I draw, say 500 bezier curves in a performant (I know, subjective) manner and yet be able to give segments different colours?

Comment: You might use a [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx) and draw the curves by the [DrawingContext.DrawGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.drawgeometry.aspx) method.

Comment: In addition to the other tips, I'd consider even the raster (i.e. bitmap) way: sometimes the vector approach become less convenient than the "old" bitmap. However, it depends on what you need.